image showed up fine, then didnt
When trying to add an image to my code, it worked at loaded fine, but now just shows the 'image failed to load' thing and the alt text. I cant fid any logical reason for it to stop working.
<img alt="Guestbook" border="0" src="https://www8.online-convert.com/v2/dl/web7/download-file/86900932-8d75-4d5e-81cc-51e9e039837a/guestbook2.png" width="160" height=160> </a>
I can send the link to my website if you want because its already public, that was you can see more

That site (online-convert.com) is an online converter site. Presumably at some point you used it to convert an image from one format to another - but the intention isn't that you then use them as an image hosting company forever.
I suggest you do the conversion again if you need to, then store the image somewhere on your own site, and make that the target of the img tag.
